# Sylow structure of $A_6$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, sylow-theory

I want to analyze the Sylow structure of $A_6$ (the alternating group of order 6),
 which has order $|A_6|=\frac{|S_6|}{2}=\frac{6!}{2}=360=2^3 3^2 5$.

Starting with $p=5$. 
We have that there are $\binom 65(5-1)!=144$ elements of order 5 in $A_6$, but given that 5 is prime, we have that the elements of order 5, are the 5-cycles, the group generated by one of this 5-cycles has $\varphi(5)=5-1=4$ generators, so we have that $|{\rm Syl}_5(A_6)|=\frac{144}{4}=36$.

If $P\in{\rm Syl}_5(A_6)$, we have that $36=|{\rm Syl}_5(A_6)|=|A_6:N_{A_6}(P)|=\frac{360}{|N_{A_6}(P)|}$, so in consequence $|N_{A_6}(P)|=10$ and I want to prove that $N_{A_6}(P)\cong D_{10}$.

By classification of groups of order 10, we have only two options for $N_{A_6}(P)$, which are $D_{10}$ (Symmetry group of a pentagon) or $C_{10}$ (Cyclic group of order 10). The difference between those is that the latter is abelian.
I don't know if part of the argument I need has to do with the fact that $A_6$ is not simple.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Shaun let me know if this is enough context, sorry if it seemed like a telegram.

Comment: This is great, voting to reopen.

Comment: Ditto. ${}{}{}$

Comment: @Shaun I'm sorry, what does "Ditto" mean?

Comment: [Here.](https://letmegooglethat.com/?q=ditto+meaning)

Comment: I feel dumb, because I searched it, before asking, but I wasn't sure if you mean that the problem with the quality standards was still unsolved. I have to say, that even if it make me feel like an idiot, I laugh at it and learned a new way to troll someone, so thank you.

Comment: It was intended to make you laugh, that's all. Happy New Year :)

Comment: Note that $(1 2 3 4 5)^{-1} = (1 5 4 3 2)$, and then the conjugate of $(1 2 3 4 5)$ by $(2 5) (3 4)$ is $(1 5 4 3 2)$.

Comment: It can't be cyclic because there are not elements of order 10 in $A_6$ (neither in $S_6$).

Comment: @moqui Thank you, that's the answer I was looking for, I realize that maybe I am dumb, because now I see, that this was pretty obvious. I'm sorry if I disappointed you.

Comment: @IvánJorroMedina everyone is in a different part of their mathematical learning. You should feel proud for making progress on yours.

If it were me thinking about teh normaliser within a group, I would start by considering the normaliser in abstract ie teh group of all isomorphisms of the group. The normaliser within the group must map into a subgroup of that.